# Why one element's CSS negative margin takes out the other element from floated box

Tags: css, css-float, padding, margin

This is piece of bigger project but what happens is that use of negative margin on one element (.pag) takes the other element (#ar_wr_in) out from floated box (#ar_wr)?

It works fine in Firefox but does not in Chrome or IE.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="ar_wr">
    <div class="pag">pagination</div>
    <div id="ar_wr_in">
      <section class="ar">isdjs fjs odifj</section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  color: #f00;
  background: #191919;
  font-family: LucidaGrande, Helvetica, Arial, sans;
}

section {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

section {
  margin: 0px;
}

#ar_wr {
  width: 59%;
  padding: 1%;
  background: #ffddff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
}

#ar_wr {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

#ar_wr_in {
  width 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.pag {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: -77px;
  /* background: #ddffff; */
  position: relative;
}

.ar {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ddffff;
}
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9hfgwg6/5/)

Is there some fix or hack for this to make it look as in Firefox?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you make your pagination element have absolute positioning then it can happily sit outside it's parent without affecting other non-absolute elements that come after it:

```
.pag {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: -77px;
  /* background: #ddffff; */
  position: absolute;
}
```

Strange that Firefox treats it differently, but I would actually expect the result that you see in Chrome from using relative positioning like that.

Comment: Thank you @Starscream1984 for your suggestion.

I have thought that absolute positioning will not work with responsive design but will try to use it like this:


`     .pag {`
       font-size: 12px;
       margin-top: -77px;
       /* background: #ddffff; */
       position: absolute;
      right: 25%;
     }`

Comment: eh, sorry

`.pag {
       font-size: 12px;
       margin-top: -77px;
       /* background: #ddffff; */
       position: absolute;
      right: 25%;
     }`

Comment: Actually using

    `position:absolute;`

together with right edge in % causes problems when resizing browser window